# How to download all links from a web address at once

Tags: download, bulk-download

I want to download all the links from this site:
http://dapds00.nci.org.au/thredds/catalogs/fk4/nidem_1_0.html

However, it will take me forever to do it manually. Is there a way to download them all without manually clicking on them one at a time?

Comment: You can get a chrome extension to bulk download, or run a script

Comment: Look into `wget`